# What is a cvs new-born file?

Tags: cvs

I get this error during checkout:

```
cvs checkout: warning: new-born file.java has disappeared
cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot make directory : No such file or directory
cvs status: cannot rewrite CVS/Entries.Backup: Permission denied
```

I'm sure I have the proper permissions to this folder and it happens even when I try to check out to a new one. I'm also sure that these files exist in cvs..

my checkout command is:

```
cvs co -d dir -N -r(num) -r(num)... file file... and so on
```

What does this new-born thing mean?

Answer (score 3):

`new-born` refers to a file that has been `add`-ed but not `commit`-ted yet, or that `CVS` is having trouble getting the file written locally.

My guess would be that there is a `.cvs` directory present that records an `add` but the file has since been deleted.

The additional errors you're seeing relate to permissions in the checkout directory - maybe you don't have write access to the checkout directory, `umask` is set incorrectly or there is a directory permission inheritance problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I know these files have already been committed into CVS.
This error also happens when I try to check these files out into a fresh directory.
Lastly, I have rwx permissions on this directory.

Comment: Double check your `umask` settings (`umask -S` in `bash`).  After executing the `cvs` command, `ls-la` and verify that a `.CVS` was created and has the correct permissions.  Otherwise, please post the exact command you're using.

Comment: BTW, where are you running the checkout?  Windows, cygwin, linux ?

Comment: Files in the CVS folder: 
Entries  Entries.Log  Entries.Static  Repository  Root
Looks pretty normal

Comment: This is probably going to require a bit of research and/or back & forth q & a.  SO may not be the best forum for that type of interaction.  The next thing I'd look at would be the repo on the server, verifying perms/ownership and that other projects/modules can be checked out w/out errors.

Comment: Roman Joki answered below and his answer is exactly what I found on our side when we go this error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was caused by specifying tag which was not present on the file. Try to remove -r from the cmd line

Comment: I had similar issue where the deployment guys where using the wrong tag to deploy. Tag did not exist on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message for a file that used to have ACLs that matched my account but no longer did.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a sticky tag setup on files in that directory but the file in question is new and has not been so tagged, then this error can occur.